# Can amp errors containing the string "Do_not_worry_about_it" be ignored?

Tags: amp-html

When testing using iphone6 mode in Chrome, the AMP validates but we are seeing console errors containing the string "Do_not_worry_about_it".

e.g.,
    https://pbs.twimg.com/amp_preconnect_polyfill_404_or_other_error_expected._Do_not_worry_about_it?0.01055807373249218

Can all console error messages containing the string "Do_not_worry_about_it" be ignored?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. We explicitly added the string "Do_not_worry_about_it" so that people would know that they're not supposed to worry about it.

See the code: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/09396b2357d56b467485e4c9ef3f5cd910a0521d/src/preconnect.js#L193 for more details.

Comment: Undocumented log entries that say "do not worry about it" are guaranteed to raise a red flag in most technical circles. If you want to provide a worry free experience I would suggest including a reference id and documenting the feature in the official AMP documentation.

Comment: That's a good idea. Can you file a feature request for this on the AMPHTML Github?